# getElementsByClassName closure problems

Tags: javascript, dom, closures

It seems like `getElementsByClassName` is being re-executed each time from outside of a closure.

I can get around this by copying the elements into an array, but I don't know if there is a better way.

Here is a code example:

HTML

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="tab">Parent Tab 1</li>
        <li class="tab">Parent Tab 2</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">Parent Content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-content">Parent Content 2</div>

    <!-- dynamically generated by javascript -->
    <div id="unrelatedContent">
        <ul>
            <li class="tab">Child Tab 1</li>
            <li class="tab">Child Tab 2</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">Child Content 1</div>
        <div class="tab-content">Child Content 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
var tabs = function(parent) {
    var tabs = parent.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    var tabContents = parent.getElementsByClassName("tab-content");
    var tabContentsById = {};
    var t1 = [];
    var t2 = [];

    //copy to an array. it seems like chrome re-evaluates
    //the getElementsByClassName part on click, meaning you cant
    //have nested tabs otherwise the parent will affect the children
    //(because itll match the childrens tab and tab-content)
    /*
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        t1.push(tabs[i]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tabContents.length; i++) {
        t2.push(tabContents[i]);
    }
    tabs = t1;
    tabContents = t2;
    */

    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        var tab = tabs[i];
        tab.onclick = function() {
            console.log(tabs);
        }
    }
}

tabs(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]);

parentTab1.click(); //length = 2

//pretend like unrelatedContent was dynamically generated via dom methods
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(unrelatedContent);
tabs(unrelatedContent);

parentTab1.click(); //length = 4
```

Comment: The `tabs` and `tabContents` variables are also known as a live set; they update to reflect changes made to the document.

Comment: did not know that. i wonder if im just out of date or never encountered this situation before... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of `document.getElementsByClassName()` is an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is a live collection of elements. If you don't want this collection to update as you add more elements to the document, you need to make a copy into an array; here's a simple way to just clone the container:

```
var tabs = [].slice.call(parent.getElementsByClassName("tab"), 0);
var tabContents = [].slice.call(parent.getElementsByClassName("tab-content"), 0);
```

See also: [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)